# Angular 2 - Emit mouse enter event to other component

Tags: angular, events

I have a component with a button, on (mouseenter) event i want to trigger a function already created in other component

the hovered button

```
<button (mouseenter)="mouseEvent()">Valid</button>
```

the function mouseEvent() should call another function in another component 
it looks simple but tricky

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  mouseEvent() {

  }
}
```

in other component i have a function

```
 execute() {
   console.log('to be executed');
 }
```

i want to execute it whenever the mouseenter event is triggered

Comment: Include the code you have tried so far in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify to

in your html

```
<button (mouseenter)="mouseEvent($event)">Valid</button>
```

in you component

```
  mouseEvent (event) {
        //do what ever you like with your event
        console.log(event)
      }
```

if you want to send data to child from this component you should declare variable in the parent and set it

```
    let myEvent:any;   

    mouseEvent (event) {
                this.myEvent = event;
              }
```

in your html

```
<childcomponent [event]="myEvent">
```

and don't forget to declare input in your child component

```
export class ChildComponent {
     @Input()event:any;
}
```

Comment: how to subscribe to that event from other components

Comment: what is the relation between this component and the component where you want to receive the event? Parent to child or they are sublings?

Comment: i want to receive the event in child component

Comment: event can be received from child to Parent, now if you are in parent and you want to send data to child you have to use `@Input()`  and pass data to child

Comment: @incertitude please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I can't do that i have a <router-outlet></router-outel> in the parent html

Comment: why you can't do that?? Router outlet doesn't prevent you to do that, can you please post the code of html page of the parent?

Comment: <button (mouseenter)="mouseEvent($event)">Valid</button>

<router-outlet [event]="event"></router-outlet>

Comment: Can't bind to 'event' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'.

Comment: why do you want to pass the event to your router outlet? you can't do this!!! I didn't know that your child was router outlet, can you explain me what you want to do please? why do you want to pass the event to router outlet?

Comment: ok, i have a button on home page (parent) when i hover the button i want a method defined in child component to be executed (my problem is simplified like that if i have a clear answer for that i will solve another problem)

Comment: this can be done using my updated answer, but couldn't be done with router outlet, my question is why do you want to pass event to router outlet?

Comment: imagine in the home component i have a header with dropdown menu with checkboxes in content area is running another component (child comonent ) which contains data, when i check in the header dropdown in the home page i want the content to be updated (invoke web service) automatically without refreshing the hole thing